# why is are my dictionary's values a list of a list

Tags: python, dictionary

The procedure below takes a list of 'parties' as input and calls the twitter api to get their followers. The result looks like:

```
{
    party1 : [[1,2,3]]
    party2 : [[e,f,g]]
}
```

But I want the values to be simple lists (i.e. [1,2,3], not [[1,2,3]]). I guess the 'page' from pages comes in as a list, but I cannot figure out how to do this any simpler. I have also tried .append instead of + below.

EDIT: As noted in the comments - page is a list. The code posted below works - I wasn't running the right version of my code. I would still be interested in why .append causes [[.]] to appear. I'm okay with closing the question too.

Here is the code:

```
def get_party_followers(parties):
    ids = {}
    for i in parties:
        l=[]
        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name=i).pages():
                l=l+page
                print "resting"
                time.sleep(60)
        ids[i]=l
        print i + " complete"
    return ids`
```

Comment: Try `extend` instead of `append`.

Comment: Looks to me that `page` is probably a list already.

Comment: But he doesn't use ``append``. He concatenates the lists and that doesn't create nested list. I suppose page might be a list too.

Comment: Print the value of `page` so you know what you're dealing with.

Comment: @cdarke That's my opinion too. Otherwise he couldn't concatenate it. That would throw an error.

Comment: If `page` is a list of elements then the code shown would be correct, while using `append` instead would give a list of lists.

Comment: Alternatively, read the documentation for `tweepy.Cursor` to see what it returns.

Comment: indeed page is a list - just verified this. i also ran the program again and it works as I originally posted it (with +). I wasn't running the updated version. I am still curious as to why append doesn't work.

Comment: If you append a list to a list it will produce a nested list. So if ``l = []`` and ``l.append(['a', b'])`` you'll get ``l = [['a', 'b']]``. You have to heed the advice of @jonrsharpe and use extend instead. Concatenating (using the + operator) is also working.

Comment: Some general notices on your coding: don't use ``l`` as a variable name. It's very confusing as someone may read it as ``1``; put a space before and after equal sign; remove the grave accent (diacritical mark) in the end of your return statement. You should always pay attention that the code posted is the code you use, because the people will base their answers upon the earlier. There are few well-intentioned advices.

Comment: If you would have ``lst = []`` and would make ``lst.append('a')`` it would produce ``lst = ['a']``, in the next step ``lst.append('b')`` would produce ``lst = ['a', 'b']``. ``append`` takes only one argument and appends it to the list as an element.

Comment: thank you both for the general and specific advice